# log function misbehaviour!!! Any clue?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

I am writing some program in C. It has a part where it does some probability calculations, where I am using log function. normal library function log()...

The code is something like this

```
double somevalue = 0.29558101472995091;
temp = log(somevalue)
```

And guess what? The temp gets value -1856.0000000000000!!!

As the value given for log was inside some struct I wrote this test code too, and got the same results...

```
int main()
{
    double somevalue;
    double temp;

    somevalue = 0.29558101472995091;
    temp = log(somevalue);
    return 0;
}

Results:
Somevalue = 0.29558101472995091
temp = -1856.0000000000000
```

Isn't it crazy. Anyone has some clue on whats going on here.

**And I am using Visual Studio 2005 for this. Can't get my hands on someother compiler now.**

Thanks,

Microkernel :)

Comment: how are you checking the value of temp? Using printf incorrectly is more likely than the log() function being wrong

Comment: For reference: log(0.29) = about -0.5

Comment: I know this doesn't help you, but running this on gcc gives me temp as a value of -1.21881.

Comment: @mmyers: Huh? It should be about -1.2188...

Comment: @mmyers: `log` computes natural log, not base-10 log!

Comment: @mmyers: There is log10 for calculating log to the base of 10. Me also gets  -1.21881

Comment: @mmyers: The c (and c++, and really, most programming languages) `log` function is base-e (not base-10), so the result should be `-1.2188..` as others have said.

Comment: You example program doesn't print/show any results. How are you seeing the results? Are you able to produce an independently compilable example that prints out the errant results on the screen? The code as written appears correct. If you're looking at the results in a debugger it may be misinterpreting them if the build is optimized.

Comment: Sorry, all. I just copied it into Google and didn't check what base it was using. Mea culpa.

Comment: @Mark B and @Martin Beckett
I'm see the results in Watch Windows by stepping through the program... But that should't be any problem right? !

Comment: @Mark B 
Its a debug build!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to `#include <math.h>` so the compiler will call `log()` correctly.

Using VC10, I get the following result from `printf ("log(%lf) = %lf\n", somevalue, temp )` when `math.h` is included:

```
log(0.295581) = -1.218812
```

If `math.h` isn't included, I get:

```
log(0.295581) = -1856.000000
```

What's probably happening is that the compiler expects the returned value from the call to `log()` to be `int` which is then converted to a `double` to store in `temp`. I don't know off the top of my head how floating point results are returned by the compiler, but I'd guess they're returned in the FP(0) register, while an int result is returned in EAX (assuming an x86 Win32 platform).  So the value to compiler gets in this case might not even have any relationship with the value the `log()` function tries to return.

If you set the warning level to `/W3` you'll get a warning about the problem:

```
C:\TEMP\test.c(10) : warning C4013: 'log' undefined; assuming extern returning int
```

In my opinion, unless you're working with a really old codebase that doesn't take advantage of function prototypes, it might make good sense to turn that warning into an error (of course, when compiled as C++ this is already an error):

```
#pragma warning( error : 4013) // or use the `/we4013` compiler option
```

Here's the compilable test:

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    double somevalue;
    double temp;

    somevalue = 0.29558101472995091;
    temp = log(somevalue);

    printf ("log(%lf) = %lf\n", somevalue, temp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This question shouldn't have the C++ tag then, since it doesn't allow calling an undeclared function with "implicit int".

Comment: Wow!!!
That really is the reason!!!

I'm wondering what the compiler is doing then if it can't find the proper log function!!! I would have expected linker error if it can't find proper function....

Hah, even after 2 years of coding in C, what a noob I am!!! 

Thanks Michael, it helped a lot!!! :)

Comment: @Microkernel I believe if you compiled it as C++ or even ANSI C this code wouldn't have compiled.

Comment: Why would someone put their warning level below the default? It *should* be at the /W4.

Comment: @Mark B, I used Visual Studio 2005 (created empty C project). isn't it ANSI-C?

Comment: Acutally, it's worse than that. If the return type is assumed to be and `int` rather than a `double` it's not even that the `double` is being read as an `int`; the return value could even be read from the wrong place. IIRC, floating point values are returned in `%st(0)` in many x86 calling conventions while integer return values are returned in `%eax` so it could be random rubbish that is being read as an `int` return.

Comment: @GMan: my VC10 compiler says that the default warning level for the compiler is 1. I mentioned level 3 because that's the level that C4013 starts showing up.

Comment: @Microkernel Compilers (especially MS) often have compatibility features and extensions enabled by default. There may be an option you have to switch on to force strict ANSI compatibility. Or just enable `/W3` like Michael Burr says in the answer.

Comment: @Microkernel - even in VC10, the MSVC compiler's C 'mode' is for ANSI C89/C90.  In that version of the C standard, function declarations aren't required - a function call without a declaration will implicitly assume an `int` is returned and that parameters will be passed using default promotions. In C99 (which MSVC doesn't support), implicit function declarations are no longer supported.

Comment: @Microkernel - also, as an FYI, by default MSVC will compile files that have a .c extension as C and .cpp files as C++.  Look at the docs for the /Tp and /Tc (and related) options for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your syntax is correct.  How are you printing your results?  If you're using a printf statement, make sure you have your format string correct.

It should go like in [this example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/log/):

```
printf ("log(%lf) = %lf\n", somevalue, temp );
```

Comment: Na it gives -1.21881 to me with both cout and the above statement.

Comment: No, I was using Watch window while stepping through the program... 
Thanks for the reply :)